# How to emulate request parameters when running a Firebase client locally

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, dialogflow-es

I've got a Google Dialogflow application I'm putting together that has a number of fulillments I need to process with external REST apis.  I've got the client set up and working with `firebase serve`, enabling me to test locally.  My index.js functions have the following siganture:

```
exports.clientEmployeeServiceCodes = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)=>{...});
```

But when I run locally any request parameter I pass through the url comes up as undefined. Here is an example.

```
http://localhost:5000/arc-caregiver-f8ec9/us-central1/clientEmployeeServiceCodes?phone=%22%%2b12123003939%22
```

But I get params when I call through Dialogflow.  So my question is whether I'm doing someting wrong or if there's a way to emulate those params in my url call so the method behaves just as it would if I called it from Dialogflow.

Here is the example where I am getting the Dialogflow parameters via the req object. Note where I get the value of **pin**.

```
exports.userHours = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res)=>{
 const start = MyUtils.getDatePlus(-14);
 const end = MyUtils.getDatePlus(14);
 var view = 'API_Pay_Periods';
 var form = 'Pay_Periods';
 var criteria = 'Pay_Period_Date >= "'+start+'" %26%26 Pay_Period_Date <= 
 "'+end+'"'
 const ret = await callRestAPI(Config,view,form,criteria);
 const pp = getPayPeriod(ret);
 const pin = req.query.pin
 console.log('pin',pin)
 const data = await RESTAPI(Config, view,form,criteria);
 res.status(200).send(response);
 ....
 res.end();
```

});

Comment: Please edit the question to show the code that isn't working the way you expect.  Are you sure the Dialogflow passes information to the function via the query string, as you're showing in that URL?

Comment: You're using the `req.query.pin` that you show in your code to get the Dialogflow POST body? That... is unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

Dialogflow sends its fulfillment information via a POST to your webhook with the [JSON object in the body of the request](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment/how-it-works#webhook_request). You cannot duplicate this by sending query parameters in the URL itself.

One typical way to work with this is to setup an [ngrok tunnel](http://ngrok.com) to your local environment and use it to record the JSON body that is sent. You can then use this same body for testing later.

Comment: I'm using Postman and doing a post, and the values still don't come through.

Comment: Are you doing a POST with the JSON body that Dialogflow sends?

Comment: Properly formatted using Postman, body info DOES come through on my local jig, My bad for not paying enough attention to the documentation.  That said, I still don't know why data is coming through the request.query object from Dialogflow.